# I want to learn all the internals and structure of the iPhone

Tags: iphone

Does anyone know of a website or resource to learn about important files / directory structures or data within the iPhone?

Soon i'll be learning to develop iPhone applications and I want to know everything about its internals, if anyone knows a resourse that would be great.

What I want to do is.

How to access the database.
Where system settings are stored.
How to gain access to the Mobile Comm Server

etc...

Answer (score 3):

All the information you'll need is available from Apple in [their developer site](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/).

File structure and other internals matter less than you'd think, as your app won't be able to get outside its sandboxed resources (unless you're writing jailbroken apps).

Answer (score 1):

[Begining IPhone Development](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1430224592) by Jeff LaMarche and David Mark

Answer (score -1):

You keep mentioning `database`.  What database are you talking about?  In your last question about gaining access to a database, I assumed it was a database that you had as part of your app.  The iPhone OS probably has many databases, including the Contacts database, the songs database, the album photos database, etc.  There are some limited ways to access this data, but they're on Apple's terms and I have to emphasize the word "limited".

As a previous respondent said, the best place to start is at Apple's [iPhone Dev Center](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/), but you won't find anything on jailbroken phones, accessing any of the cell or communication systems, nor the system settings, among many other things.

Comment: I'm fairly sure the iPhone has an SQL database installed.

Comment: Just one?  iPhone has SQLite installed.  Each application may have any number of databases that SQLite can offer up.  These databases live in the sandboxed area of each app.  And by "live" I mean where the data for the database exists.  There may be one SQLite, but there are many databases.  And we're not even talking about the databases belonging to Core Data.